# Race condition with rails sessions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, conditional-statements, race-condition

There is an array inside the session hash which I'm adding things to it. The problem is, sometimes multiple requests get processed at the same time (because ajax), and the changes a request makes to the array is then replaced by the changes made by the second request.

Example, the array first looks like this:

> [63, 73, 92]

Then the first request adds something to it:

> [63, 73, 92, 84]

The second request does the same thing (but works on the older version obviously):

> [63, 73, 92, 102]

So in the end the array doesn't look like it should. Is there a way to avoid that?
I tried to use the cache store, the active record store and the cookie store. Same problem with all of them.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know what else you are doing on the server side but what about http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Optimistic.html

Answer (score 2):

Session race conditions are very common in Rails. Redis session store doesn't help either!
The reason is Rails only reads and creates the session object when it receives the request and writes it back to session store when request is complete and is about to be returned to user.

Java has a solution for this called session replication. We can build our own concurrent redis based session store. The following is pretty much it. Except the update method is missing the lock. But it almost never happens to get race condition in it.

To get session hash just use concurrent_session which returns a hash.
To set some value in it, use update_concurrent_session method. It deep merges the new hash into the old value:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def concurrent_session
    @concurrent_session ||= get_concurrent_session
  end

  def update_concurrent_session h
    return unless session.id.present?
    @concurrent_session = get_concurrent_session.deep_merge(h)
    redis.set session_key, @concurrent_session.to_json
    redis.expire session_key, session_timeout
  end

  private

  def redis
    Rails.cache.redis
  end

  def session_timeout
    2.weeks.to_i
  end

  def session_key
    'SESSION_' + session.id.to_s if session.id.present?
  end

  def get_concurrent_session
    return {} unless session.id.present?
    redis.expire session_key, session_timeout
    redis.get(session_key).yield_self do |v|
      if v
        JSON.parse v, symbolize_names: true
      else
        {}
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Usage example:

```
my_roles = concurrent_session[:my_roles]
update_concurrent_session({my_roles: ['admin', 'vip']})
```

Answer (score 1):

There really isn't a great solution for this in Rails. My first suggestion would be to examine your use case and see if you can avoid this situation to begin with. If it's safe to do so, session data if often best kept on the client, as there are a number of challenges that can come up when dealing with server-side session stores. On the other hand, if this is data that might be useful long term across multiple page requests (and maybe multiple sessions), perhaps it should go in the database.

Of course, there is some data that really does belong in the session (a good example of this is the currently logged-in user). If this is the case, have a look at http://paulbutcher.com/2007/05/01/race-conditions-in-rails-sessions-and-how-to-fix-them/, and specifically https://github.com/fcheung/smart_session_store, which tries to deal with the situation you've described.

Answer (score 1):

It is a simple race condition, just lock the request using any locking mechanism like
[redis locker](https://github.com/einzige/redis-locker)

```
RedisLocker.new('my_ajax').run! { session[:whatever] << number }
```

Comment: I think your lock would have to be around the entire request for this to work

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Load the current session, or create a new one if necessary
> 2. Save a copy of the unmodified session for future reference
> 3. Run the code of the action
> 4. Compare the modified session with the copy saved previously to determine what has changed
> 5. If the session has changed:
>
>    1. Lock the session
>    2. Reload the session
>    3. Apply the changes made to this session and save it
>    4. Unlock the session

From [Race conditions in Rails sessions and how to fix them](http://paulbutcher.com/2007/05/01/race-conditions-in-rails-sessions-and-how-to-fix-them/).